# Argument variable cannot be resolved

Tags: java, constructor

```
import java.util.*; 

public class Graph 
{
  Graph(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> adjList) 
  {
    this.adjList = adjList;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to create a class for graphs, and it takes in an adjacency list, i.e a list of lists (of integers) in defining the graph. I don't want my constructor to do anything except take the adjacency list and let me use it in other class methods. But when I write the above code, I get the following error message; "adjList cannot be resolved or is not a field." What's up with that? How do I fix it?

Comment: What do you think `this.adjList` represents? Why do you think so?

Comment: `private ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> adjList`  FTFY it is now a field

Comment: You need to add `adjList` as a field in the class, as well as an argument to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

As @scary pointed you can use below code with field added

```
import java.util.*;
public class Graph{ 
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>adjList;
    Graph(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>adjList){
         this.adjList = adjList; 
  } 
}
```

Note: If you want use same list for all of the instances created, you can mark (declare) it as static.